# revome lines from .txt in python

Tags: python, dna-sequence

I have the following .txt:

TITLE     Genetic variation in the complete MgPa operon and its repetitive
chromosomal elements in clinical strains of Mycoplasma genitalium

JOURNAL   PLoS ONE 5 (12), E15660 (2010)

PUBMED   21187921

REMARK    Publication Status: Online-Only

REFERENCE   3  (bases 1 to 1480)

PUBMED   21997874

REFERENCE   4  (bases 1 to 1480)

REFERENCE   5  (bases 1 to 1480)

AUTHORS   Ma,L., Jensen,J.S., Jia,Q., Mancuso,M.A., Myers,L.J. and
Martin,D.H.

TITLE     Direct Submission

ORIGIN
1 agtaagaatg ttactgctta cacccccttc gccaccccca tcaccgattc taaaagtgat
61 ctggttagtt tggcacaact tgattcttct tatcaaatcg ctgaccaaac catccataac
121 accaacttgt ttgtgttgtt caagtccaag gatgtgaagc ttacatatag ttcaagtggc
181 tcaaataacc agattagttt tgattcaact agtcaaggtg aaaaaccatc ctatgtggtc
241 gagtttacta actctaccaa cattggcatc aagtgaagcg tggtgaaaaa gtatcagtta
301 gatctaccaa atgttaccaa tgagatgaac caagtgttgc aagaattgat cctagaacaa
361 ccccttacca agtatacctt aaacagtagt ttggctaaac aaaagggcaa aagccagata
421 gaggtacatc ttggttcaaa ttcaaatcag tgacaatcga tgcgtaatca acatgaccta
481 aacaacaatc ccagccccaa tgcttcaact gggtttaaac tcactaccgg caacgcatat
541 agaaaattaa atgagtcctg accaatttat caaccaattg atgggaccaa gcagggcaaa
601 gggaaggata gtagtgggtg gagttcaaca gaagcaacaa cggcaaaaaa tgatgcgccc
661 agtgtttctg gaagtggaac atcagacacc gcttcaaaat tcaaaagtta cctcaacacc
721 aagcaagcgt tagagagcat cggcatcttg tttgatgggg atggaatgag gaatgtggtt
781 acccagctct attatgcttc tactagcaag ctagcagtca ccaacaacca cattgtcgtg
841 atgggtaaca gctttctacc cagcatgtgg tactgggtgg tggagcggag tgcaacaact
901 gattcatcat caaaacccac ctggtttgct aataccaatt taaactgagg ggaagataaa
961 caaaaacaat ttgttgagaa ccagttgggg tataaggaaa ctaccagtac caattcccac
1021 aacttccatt ccaaatcttt cacccaacct gcatatctga tcagtggcat tgacagtgtc
1081 aatgatcaaa tcatcttcag tggctttaaa gcggggagtg tggggtatga tagtagtagt
1141 agtagtagta gtagtagtag tagtagtacc aaagaccaag cacttgcttg atcaacaaca
1201 actagcttag atagtaaaac ggggtatagg gatctagtga ccaacgacac ggggctaaat
1261 ggtccgatca atgggagttt ttcaatccaa gacaccttca gctttgttgt tccttattcg
1321 gggaatcata caaattcaag tggttcatca ggacccatta aaactgctta tccagtgaaa
1381 aaagatcaaa aatcaactgt caagatcaat tctttgatta acgctacgcc cttgaatagt
1441 tatggggatg aggggattgg ggtgtttgat gcgttaggtt
//

And I want to create a new one where the output is like this.

agtaagaatg ttactgctta cacccccttc gccaccccca tcaccgattc taaaagtgat
ctggttagtt tggcacaact tgattcttct tatcaaatcg ctgaccaaac catccataac
accaacttgt ttgtgttgtt caagtccaag gatgtgaagc ttacatatag ttcaagtggc
tcaaataacc agattagttt tgattcaact agtcaaggtg aaaaaccatc ctatgtggtc
gagtttacta actctaccaa cattggcatc aagtgaagcg tggtgaaaaa gtatcagtta
gatctaccaa atgttaccaa tgagatgaac caagtgttgc aagaattgat cctagaacaa
ccccttacca agtatacctt aaacagtagt ttggctaaac aaaagggcaa aagccagata
gaggtacatc ttggttcaaa ttcaaatcag tgacaatcga tgcgtaatca acatgaccta
aacaacaatc ccagccccaa tgcttcaact gggtttaaac tcactaccgg caacgcatat
agaaaattaa atgagtcctg accaatttat caaccaattg atgggaccaa gcagggcaaa
gggaaggata gtagtgggtg gagttcaaca gaagcaacaa cggcaaaaaa tgatgcgccc
agtgtttctg gaagtggaac atcagacacc gcttcaaaat tcaaaagtta cctcaacacc
aagcaagcgt tagagagcat cggcatcttg tttgatgggg atggaatgag gaatgtggtt
acccagctct attatgcttc tactagcaag ctagcagtca ccaacaacca cattgtcgtg
atgggtaaca gctttctacc cagcatgtgg tactgggtgg tggagcggag tgcaacaact
gattcatcat caaaacccac ctggtttgct aataccaatt taaactgagg ggaagataaa
caaaaacaat ttgttgagaa ccagttgggg tataaggaaa ctaccagtac caattcccac
aacttccatt ccaaatcttt cacccaacct gcatatctga tcagtggcat tgacagtgtc
aatgatcaaa tcatcttcag tggctttaaa gcggggagtg tggggtatga tagtagtagt
agtagtagta gtagtagtag tagtagtacc aaagaccaag cacttgcttg atcaacaaca
actagcttag atagtaaaac ggggtatagg gatctagtga ccaacgacac ggggctaaat
ggtccgatca atgggagttt ttcaatccaa gacaccttca gctttgttgt tccttattcg
gggaatcata caaattcaag tggttcatca ggacccatta aaactgctta tccagtgaaa
aaagatcaaa aatcaactgt caagatcaat tctttgatta acgctacgcc cttgaatagt
tatggggatg aggggattgg ggtgtttgat gcgttaggtt

How can I tell to the console that I want a new file but just from ORIGIN till the end?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? What problems did you run into? Please ask specific questions, and provide some example of code to show what you're able to do, focus on a specific problem - don't expect SO to write your code for you. Have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to create a .txt from a certain line, this could work for you:

```
flag = false
with open("src.txt", "r") as src:
    with open("dst.txt", "w") as dst:
        for line in src:
            if(flag == True):
                dst.write(line)
            if(line.__contains__('ORIGIN')):
                flag = True
```

This iterates through the lines in the source file and whenever it finds the word 'ORIGIN' starts writing what's in the src file into the dst file.

Comment: this works but `flag == True` is ugly and branching while iterating over the while file is inefficient.

Comment: YES IT WORKS!!! BUT the F of false is in capital letter: False

Comment: @bubukerokero yep, my bad. I've being with ts lately and got used to false :/ Glad it worked tho :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you also want to remove any numbers and slashes. Therefore you could do this:

```
import re
import sys
with open('infile.txt', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
    try:
        while not next(infile).startswith('ORIGIN'):
            pass
        with open('outfile.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(re.sub(r'[\d+|/]', '', line).lstrip())
    except StopIteration:
        print('ORIGIN not found', file=sys.stderr)
```